# Run class member function in separate thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, boost, std-function, stdbind

Good time of the day! I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with boost 1.66. Currently, I'm trying to run class member function in a separate thread using boost.

```
void ServerWorkerTh()
{

}

void StartServer() const
{
    auto f = boost::bind(&NetworkCore::ServerWorkerTh, this);
    boost::thread th(f);
}
```

But I'm getting

> error C2440: 'argument': cannot convert from 'const NetworkCore' to
>   'NetworkCore &'

It seems that compiler want to receive a reference to a real object, but I'm actually giving him `this`. Is it possible to run class member function in a separate thread without using lambdas?

Comment: `void ServerWorkerTh()` and `void StartServer() const`. One of these things is not like, um, the other. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: Uh! That was my hard fail